# Laravel - Permanent validation for specific field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-5.8

There are many places in my website where I request people specify their phone number or another types of data. Each place, the validation rules are the same, and chaining the same validation rules over and over again within every validator is not so pretty, and bad for future updates for the validation rules. Think about it, when I want to change the phone number validation rules for example, I need to change it on every form validator.

I know I can add custom validation rules using extensions and add some normal php conditions in order to achieve the desired validation, but it is not exactly what I want to do because I want to use several Laravel validations, and not to add a validation of my own.

Is there any way to do that? I went through all Laravel documentation and I didn't find any way of how can I do that.

Comment: Did you try to this [create form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) ??

Comment: @Jovs They are talking there about creating a full form validation, it's not related to specific fields.

Comment: I think you want to create a validator for all of your form at once since they're the same right?

Comment: @Jovs No, I want to create a validator for specific field (like email, phone) that will automatically be added to all forms contains this field. For example, I have login, registration and password recovery forms, they're all contain phone number. I want the phone number in all forms to be validated with the following rules: 'required|max:12'. How can I define the rules specifically for phone field in all forms, without repeating the rules on every form validator?

Comment: That's why I suggest that you can create a form request and just used it for the specific field that you want then just call it all in your controller function, as long as it is the same field name then it will validate.

Comment: You can just put there the (email or phone) validation then the rest for each form, you can validate normally like what you're doing. The purpose of it is you can just call that and have the same validation of (phone and email) without repeating the validation and you can just edit the form request if you want to change something

Comment: @Jovs The phone and email are just examples. Actually I need to define something like 20 fields with permanent rules and it's not efficient to create a form request for each one of them.

Comment: I see, the other way around I can think is use javascript orrrrrrrrrrrr a `controller function(can be also a new controller)` that validate them if its exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198113/discussion-between-itzhak-avraham-and-jovs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a good approach would be to create a `UsesCommonRules` Trait containing a method named `getCommonRules()`, which would return an array with the rules.

```php
namespace App\Traits;

trait UsesCommonRules 
{
    public static function getCommonRules(){
        return [
            'date' => 'required|date',
            'type' => 'in:A,B'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, you can merge any other rules with the common rules inside of a Request or directly in the Controller if you are validating there.

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Traits\UsesCommonRules;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use UsesCommonRules;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(self::getCommonRules(), [
            'city_id' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can make more dynamic functions in the `UsesCommonRules` trait, such as receiving parameters for what rules should be returned, excluded, or combine rules for fields with the same name.

Comment: I like this approach. But if I use this array inside a validator of form which not supposed to contain a field called `date`, this field will be required anyway even if I don't want it to be.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can create methods in the trait that filter what rules are brought. In fact, you can create more static methods with different rule sets.